# Capturing variables from a CSV file determined by numeric range in a Windows Batch File

Tags: batch-file

I have the following data in a # delimited CSV data file called `clean.txt`:

```
1 LINK#FSN News Cart#<< DO NOT DELETE or MOVE >>#0#27000 
2 LINK#News Outro#<< DO NOT DELETE or MOVE >>#27000#33000 
3 SONG#Blow My Mind (feat. Chris Brown)#Davido#33000#199000 
4 SONG#So Good#Alex Blue#199000#361000 
5 SONG#Easy To Love (feat. Teddy Swims)#Armin van Buuren and Matoma#367000#517000 
6 SONG#Anti-Hero (Roosevelt Remix)#Taylor Swift#517000#725000 
7 SONG#Simmer (feat. Burna Boy) (Majestic Remix)#Mahalia#730000#929000 
8 SONG#Pyramid (Michael Calfan Remix)#John Dahlback#929000#1121000 
9 SONG#I Told You Once#Si Sax#1121000#1311000 
10 SONG#I'm Every Woman#Whitney Houston and SG Lewis#1311000#1538000 
11 SONG#Overnight#Tobtok and Adam Griffin#1544000#1698000 
12 SONG#Hungry (For Love)#LF SYSTEM#1698000#1840000 
13 LINK#Slogan#Theme A#1840000#1849000 
14 SONG#If You Want Me To Stay (Eric Kupper Edit)#The Lovefreekz and Nick Reach Up#1849000#2029000 
15 SONG#Never Too Late#Olivia Nelson#2029000#2220000 
16 SONG#Celestial#Ed Sheeran#2224000#2427000 
17 SONG#Out Of My Depth (feat. Nu-La)#CHANEY#2427000#2595000 
18 SONG#All By Myself#Alok, Sigala and Ellie Goulding#2595000#2761000 
19 SONG#Sweet Lies#Nathan Dawe and Talia Mar#2761000#2880000 
20 SONG#Down In Atlanta#Pharrell Williams and Travis Scott#2882000#3038000 
21 SONG#More Than Ever#Harry Shadow and Jodapac#3038000#3216000 
22 SONG#What You Gonna Do (feat. Taet)#CLIK3D#3216000#3391000 
23 SONG#Let It Go#Ryan Shepherd#3391000#3555000 
24 SONG#2 Be Loved (Am I Ready) (PNAU Remix)#Lizzo#3555000#3773000 
25 SONG#Perfect Love#Tom Westy and Mila Falls#3773000#3931000 
26 LINK#ID#Theme A#3931000#3936000 
27 LINK#Website Promo#HHUK#3936000#3974000 
28 LINK#News Intro and Bed - WITH FADE#<< DO NOT DELETE or MOVE >>#3974000#3983000
```

The fields on each row are:

```
<ITEM>#<TITLE>#<ARTISTS>#<START>#<END>
```

START and END are integers in milliseconds.

The objective is to display the `<TITLE> - <ARTIST>` that corresponds to a time between `<START> and <END>` The time is provided in an input variable.

The following script works with a hard-coded input variable (Dur) of **1000000 or less**, but if I go above that I get multiple results and I can’t figure out why.

```
set /a Dur=1000000

for /F "tokens=1-5 delims=#" %%i in (clean.txt) do (

    If %Dur% GEQ %%l (if %Dur% LEQ %%m echo %%i %%l %%m TRACK %%k - %%j)
)
```

I have tried dividing all of the numbers in the data file by 1000 to reduce the size but that didn’t make any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily (and fast) solve this problem this way:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set /a Dur=1000000

for /F "tokens=1-5 delims=#" %%i in (clean.txt) do (
   set /A "inRange=((%%l-Dur)>>31)*((Dur-%%m)>>31)"
   if !inRange! EQU 1 echo %%i %%l %%m TRACK %%k - %%j
)
```

The rationale of the used formula is explained with detail at [this post](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3493). This is a summary:

```
set /A (lowerLimit-variable)            is negative if variable > lowerLimit
set /A (variable-UpperLimit)            is negative if variable < upperLimit, so
set /A (lowLimit-var)*(var-UpLimit)     is positive if variable is in range
```

In this case the result of the subtractions is reduced to a **-1** or **0** values with an **>>31** arithmetic shift right of 31 bits in order to avoid any overflow when large values are multiplied.

Comment: Thank you. This works extremely well and is much faster than the previous example.

Answer (score 1):

Your comparisons are bein performed alphabetically; `1` as the first character in a string is always less than any other digit.

You need to force arithmetic comparison, or find a way around the string-comparison.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
set /a Dur=1200000

for /F "tokens=1-5 delims=#" %%i in (q75313286.txt) do (
 rem will set cond1 to +ve if first condition is true, -ve otherwise
 SET /a cond1=%dur% - %%l
 rem ditto second condition
 SET /a cond2=%%m - %dur%
 ECHO !cond1!!cond2! |FIND "-">NUL
 rem if either is negative, errorlevel will be 0
 IF ERRORLEVEL 1 echo %%i %%l %%m TRACK %%k - %%j
 rem If %Dur% GEQ %%l (if %Dur% LEQ %%m echo %%i %%l %%m TRACK %%k - %%j)
)
GOTO :EOF
```

**Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.**

I used a file named `q75313286.txt` containing your data for my testing.

---- Improved "for" loop

```
for /F "tokens=1-5 delims=#" %%i in (q75313286.txt) do (
 rem will set cond1 to +ve if first condition is true, -ve otherwise
 SET /a cond1=%dur% - %%l
 rem ditto second condition
 SET /a cond2=%%m - %dur%
 SET "cond1=!cond1!!cond2!"
 IF "!cond1!"=="!cond1:-=!" echo %%i %%l %%m TRACK %%k - %%j
 rem If %Dur% GEQ %%l (if %Dur% LEQ %%m echo %%i %%l %%m TRACK %%k - %%j)
)
```

By concatenating the results of the two calculations, you get a string that may contain 0,1 or 2 `-` characters.

Instead of checking that string by way of `echo...find...`, see whether the string is the same as [the same string, with `-` replaced by *nothing*]. If it is, then there are no `-` characters in the string. This is a lot faster than the `echo...find...` method (albeit insignificant - it's the principle)

Comment: Thank you. I would never have worked that out. Works perfectly.

Comment: It seems at first that your method incorrectly reports the `9 SONG` instead of the correct `8 SONG`, but this happens because you modified the original `set /a Dur=1000000` data...